# Is my server in RAID mode at all?

Tags: raid

I am out of means to find out if my server is using RAID or not. If yes, which mode? The server is connected with the disk array box. So I am pretty sure that it's supposed to use RAID. Can it not?

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

I got this:

```
Personalities:
unused devices: <none>
```

Here is df result

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on                                                                            
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00                                                                                                               
                      72656340  17564032  51342012  26% /                                                                                     
/dev/sda1               101086     25149     70718  27% /boot                                                                                 
tmpfs                  1029744         0   1029744   0% /dev/shm                                                                              
/dev/mapper/VolGroup--MD1000-DATA--01                                                                                                         
                     2113529792 1749272544 364257248  83% /opt
```

Comment: With what kind of disk array box is your server connected and how? It's quite possible that this box is a RAID box, but you will not notice if it is configured as RAID because it will handle all this RAID stuff internally and present itself to the server as one big disk. In this case, the server has no standard way to identify the disk as a RAID volume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This array, the Dell PowerVault MD1000 is normally connected to a PERC 5E/6E or H800 card, as Robin says you can see the configuration of the RAID controller pressing CTRL + R during the post.

Also, if you have a supported OS (Red Hat or SUSE Enterprise Linux, VMWare ESX), you can install OMSA to see the hardware configuration, the files to install it can be found in support.dell.com.

If you have Ubuntu or Debian you can install the community version of OMSA, check this link http://dell.to/wcN71S for more info about OMSA.

Answer (score 5):

It's likely that your server is using some sort of hardware RAID card, not software RAID. When using hardware RAID, the card itself takes care of all RAID tasks, and presents a single volume to the operating system.

Look through the output of `dmesg` and `lspci`. If a RAID card is present, evidence of it should show up in one (or both) of those places.

Comment: could you please define "evidence", do you mean that, e.g. `dmesg | grep -ir raid` should return some information, like in my case "device-mapper: dm-raid45: initialized v0.2594l"?

Answer (score 2):

If the server uses hardware RAID, you can usually find the management screen during BIOS bootup.  Watch for a message telling you to press a particular key combo to enter the utility. What kind of hardware is it?

Comment: Dell PE860 + Powervault MD1000

Answer (score 0):

I believe that will be connected to a Dell PERC card if using a Dell supplied config.

After a reboot, enter Control - R when prompted and you will be able to get into the RAID BIOS and confirm the config.